# Изменение значения поля при изменении сделки Битрикс24

Tags: php, api, битрикс, битрикс24

коллеги.
Столкнулся с проблемой, связанной с API Битрикс24 (облачная версия).
Делаю логику следующую:

- создал исходящий вебхук, который вызывается при изменении сделки (по идее, мне достаточно изменение одного поля только);
- вебхук обращается к скрипту на сервере, который обрабатывает данные и записывает данные в другое поле методом crm.deal.update

Все срабатывает нормально, но зацикливается. Т.е. пользователь руками меняет значение одного поля, срабатывает вебхук и затем выполняется crm.deal.update, что в свою очередь запускает опять-таки вебхук.

Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобным или подскажет, каким образом можно переделать обработчик, чтобы не было зацикливания?

Comment: Если достаточно изменения только одного поля, то проверяйте перед непосредственно вызовом веб-хука что было изменение именно в нем. Либо же сделайте флаг был уже запуск или нет и работайте с ним.